# using #define in functions

Tags: c, function, variables

How do i make it so that i can use #define variables in my functions? I need to create a program that calls upon functions with this code. Basically my functions at the bottom can change but my main function cannot change from this kind of format, so however i write my functions i have to pass the variable a and variable SIZE through the functions. But current it seems that SIZE is not actually recognized as an int variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 9

int i, position, tmp;

void readArray(int a[]);
void printArray(int a[]);
void sortArray(int a[]);

int main(void)
{
int a[SIZE];

readArray(a);

printArray(a);

sortArray(a);

printf("After sorting:\n");

printArray(a);

return 0;
}


//Functions//
void readArray(int a[]){
printf("Please enter %d integers: ", SIZE);
    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
}

void printArray(int a[]){
for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {
        printf("a[%d] = %3d\n", i, a[i]);
    }
}

void sortArray(int a[]){
for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        // In each iteration, the i-th largest number becomes the i-th array  element.
        // Find the largest number in the unsorted portion of the array and
        // swap it with the number in the i-th place.

        for (position=i; position<SIZE; position++) {
            if (a[i] < a[position]) {
                tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[position];
                a[position] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might like to read about macros in particular and about the C pre-processor in general.

Comment: Also indenting your code helps keeping the overview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing

```
 #define SIZE 9
```

will tell the preprocessor to replace each appearance of SIZE with 9.
meaning, the following line -

```
void sortArray(int a[], int SIZE)
```

will be replaced with -

```
void sortArray(int a[], int 9)
```

I assume you understand this is illegal.
You should just delete the second function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename the C variables to something *other* than `SIZE`. This is already used by the preprocessor. Also, watch out because you've written `Int` instead of `int`.